# parse string into substrings c#

Tags: c#, string

I've been given this string below. It's not something I can change either. I need to create a for-loop which goes through this string and creates a list of substrings based on each 'object'. Is there something in regex which would allow me to break this into the desired target? I'm not very familiar with parsing methods in C#. Advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

**Supplied STRING**

```
{
    [#HEADER_15618] = {
        {
            name = "Donuts",
            isEnabled = true,
            isWired = false,
        },
        {
            name = "Test",
            isEnabled = true,
            isWired = false,
        },
    },
}
```

**desired output**

```
List<string> strings = 
{
    "{
        name = "Donuts",
        isEnabled = true,
        isWired = false,
    }",
    "{
        name = "Test",
        isEnabled = true,
        isWired = false,
    }",
}
```

Keeping in mind that the number of items change change it's not always just two. And the number inside the #HEADER is not always the same.

Comment: What a shame. This is damn near json

Comment: Aaaaaaaand what have you tried?

Comment: Thanks for the update. Is there a question?

Comment: First thought. String.replace { and }. then trim everything. that way you have blah=blah, every entry will be comma delimited. IF you placed one in your last entry in brackets

Comment: How is this different from parsing a normal JSON string?

Comment: Key: Value <-JSON (Colon)

Comment: I liked the orders -> "Keep In Mind"..Ok Sir !

Comment: Could you String.replace("=", ":"), then parse as json?

Comment: @FirebladeDan No you won't. That is perfectly legal in C#.

Comment: @BradfordDillon- dafuq. It does work! Why would they allow that. Is the question.. good catch. Removing for confusion sake.

Comment: @FirebladeDan It is what it is. It confuses a lot of JavaScript people here who move over to C# and see it for the first time.

Comment: Solve a simpler problem. Can you write a *tokenizer*? That is, a method that takes in the string and produces a sequence of token strings. A tokenizer for English would take "Hello, world!" and produce the sequence "Hello", "," ,"world", "!".  You won't be able to write a parser if you cannot write a tokenizer, so start with that problem.

Comment: Also, is it the case that the desired output is full of ill-formed string literals?  Because that;'s what you've shown here. Surely those should be verbatim string literals with escaped quotation marks, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this is a kind of a hack solution. I'm sure there are better ways to handle it using Regex as such I would suggest you add a regex tag to your post to get some of the regex gurus in here.

```
var strings = input.Split(new string[] { "= {", "}," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                   .Skip(1)
                   .Select(x => x.Trim())
                   .Where(x => x.StartsWith("{"))
                   .Select(x => x + " }")
                   .ToList();
```

Start by splitting the string based on two strings. The first one gets rid of the header, the other splits the objects up. Next, skip the first one as it is the header which we don't want. Then find all entries that start with a `{` to get rid of the last few entries which we also don't want. Then we use another `Select` to append a `}` back on that was eaten by the `string.Split()`.

Again, by no means is this an efficient solution, especially if the input string contains a lot of objects as it creates a lot of strings in the process of processing the input. Regex probably offers a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

```
^\s*{\s*\[#.*\]\s*=\s*{\s*{(.*)}\s*,\s*{(.*)}\s*,?\s*}\s*,?\s*}\s*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/kiZCSZLO1uITcH6D)

Then take the 2 captured groups and put the '{' and '}' on the ends